# How do I configure clients at Authentication Server for SPA - REST architecture with validation?

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect, keycloak

I know this topic has been around a lot and there are a lot of tickets already. But after looking at hundreds of tickets and pages I didn't find the necessary architecture informations.

What I plan is a simple SPA (Angular) - REST Backend (separate .Net Core 2.1 WebApi) setup. I have Keycloak to provide authentication via OpenId Connect. I'm using a OpenId package for Angular to communicate with Keycloak, to get the id and access tokens.

What I would like to have is that the Angular client only has access to identity token and the information isAuthenticated/LoggedIn. The access token should not be of interest for the Angular frontend, right? So I could also encrypt the access token to secure information?

I'm then passing the encrypted access token to my REST-Backend (has access to app secret) where I can validate encrypted signature, the encrypted body of the token and maybe introspect token at Authentication Server to validate and grant access to resources?

But why does so many articles state that a Keycloak confidential client (has an app secret) is not a proper way for SPA setup? The SPA itself doesn't need the secret, only the backend does, or not?

Please I would appreciate any information that helps me to close the remaining gaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The access token should not be of interest for the Angular frontend, right?

Yes ,  you client only need to validate and decode the ID token to get user's profile information  .Access token is to access protected resource , which is not need to validate the access token in client app .

> So I could also encrypt the access token to secure information?

Not sure if I understand your scenario . JWTs can be either signed, encrypted or both, that is controlled by token service . When your backend web api receives access token , it will validate the access token , validate the signature with the public key published by identity provider .

> But why does so many articles state that a Keycloak confidential client (has an app secret) is not a proper way for SPA setup?

Nowadays it is recommended to use the authorization code grant flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) to secure the Angular app. It's more secure than keeping  client secret in spa application . I'm not familiar with Keycloak , but you can click [here](https://ordina-jworks.github.io/security/2019/08/22/Securing-Web-Applications-With-Keycloak.html#implicit-flow-versus-code-flow--pkce)  for article about how to use code flow + PKCE in Angular app using Keycloak as IDP .

Comment: Hello @NanYu and thank you for your answer. That already helps me a little bit. My scanario is running in an intranet / private network which does at the moment not use https. This is why I would like to encrypt the access token. Id token has only basic information (user name). Does that mean a client at authentication server with app secret is in general not suitable for authorization code flow (PKCE)? I'll have a look at your link about the topic

Comment: Keycloak supports authorization code flow (PKCE) . So you can use authorization code flow (PKCE) in angular app . And you can encrypt the access token , that is up to you .